# JavaScript - Date from 9 pm to next day morning 9 am

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

I want to set the dates between 9 P.M - next day 9 A.M.

```
  var set_min;
  var set_max;
  if ( hours >= 9 && hours <= 17 ) // 9 AM to 5 PM
  {
      day_part = "Lunch";
       set_min = 9;
       set_max = 17;      

  }
  else if (hours >= 18 && hours <= 21 ) // 6 PM to 9 PM
  {
      day_part = "Snack";
       set_min = 18; 
       set_max = 21;
  }
  else
  {
      day_part = "Dinner";

// Here i want to make it from 10 PM to 9 AM Next day
       set_min = 22;
       set_max = 9;

  }
```

If i set like this. When i try to pass these values in condition First two Lunch and Snack works fine.But Dinner is not showing the correct results.

```
     var passintime = new Date(data[i].passintime).getHours(); 
     if (passintime >=set_min && passintime < set_max)
{

// my code
}
```

I want the dinner to show from previous day 10 PM to next day morning 9 AM.

Comment: Why do you want to check afterwards? Your `if else` logic works fine.

Comment: For the last condition (dinner), you need `passintime >=set_min || passintime < set_max`, which is inconsistent with the other two cases.

Comment: Thanks . Is there any other way i can make all three conditions works. or how can i modify the code.

Comment: Take in spelling “JavaScript” to avoid search collisions with Java.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Date instead hours

```
mindate=date;
mindate=mindate.setHour(22);
maxdate=date;
maxdate=maxdate.setDate(maxdate.getDate()+1).setHour(9);
if (mindate>x && x<maxdate)
```

where date  is current date